# Can I use HttpModule for handling 404 errors on static files without writing custom a HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler, httpmodule, static-files

I wrote a http module that I intended to use for capturing 404 responses from static files (and generate them on the fly). However the error handler in the module fails to capture errors from static files (works for MVC routes etc.).

I know I can write a http handler that can do this, but I wanted to keep file handling as simple as possible.

So my question is, **is it even possible to handle static file errors in a http module without getting rid of the** `StaticFile` **http handler** (i.e. providing a path that will override it)?

P.S. I know I can make an aspx error page that could do what I want, but I need to avoid doing redirects and the error page solution would result in no less than two (which is no good).